# Grass High Polly to low poly for Unreal Engine?

Tags: modeling, texturing

i have question aboud create grass. 
Now i have high poly model like this :

[image]

How Can I do this in blender :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no easy method for that. Your vegetation is a real and detailed 3D model while the example below uses the efficient *billboard* technique - each model consists of several polygons textured by semi-transparent images / photos.
Because both approaches are really different, you cannot simply get the second one by reducing the mesh detail or any other automatic method.

If you want to use your 3D vegetation to create a billboard one, **you can render you 3D vegetation from different angles to png textures** (with the transparency). Then **create simple models for each flower** / grass cluster etc (like in the example) **and apply png textures you have rendered** on them.

Comment: So i have question for you, what a method is te best for creating grass for games engine ?

Comment: There is no definite answer for that as it depends on many factors. If you are going to make a mobile game, you need as simple models as possible while for a first-person PC shooter game it can me much more detailed of course. I would just try to see how the vegetation is made in a project similar to yours (using the same graphics engine) and then find out how is it made, whether you can obtain some vegetation assets packs etc.
This can be useful for you? https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/30694-free-foliage-starter-kit

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help :) I have last question, i want to create models for PC Games, yes i know i must to use more detailed models, but i can't use this grass : http://prntscr.com/go3rn9 because my PC can not stand it? I must use like this : http://prntscr.com/go3s3w 
of course transparent e.t.c. I'm right?

Comment: The second (billboard) method is sufficient for the most cases so it shouldn't be problem :)